# Play integration test with browser that supports WebSocket

Tags: playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0

I am trying to do some simple integration tests with my WebSocket code using WithBrowser:

```
  class ApplicationControllerSpec extends Specification{
    "Application Controller" should {
      "do something" in new WithBrowser{
        browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333")
        browser.pageSource must contain("Hello")
      }
    }
  }
```

When I do this I get a very long error but part of it says:

> WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException:
>   ReferenceError: "WebSocket" is not defined.

Is there an alternative WebDriver that does have WebSocket implemented? Alternatively, is there a way to have it actually open up firefox or chrome?

I would also appreciate any advice on how to test WebSocket code, but it looks like there is another unanswered question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354354/test-websocket-in-playframework).

I am using Play 2.1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test WebSockets with Firefox:

https://github.com/schleichardt/stackoverflow-answers/commit/13d5876791ef409e092e4a097f54247d851e17dc#L8R14

`WithBrowser` supports as first argument the Browser, see [Doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.x/scala/index.html#play.api.test.WithBrowser).

So it could look like

```
 class ApplicationControllerSpec extends Specification{
    "Application Controller" should {
      "do something" in new WithBrowser(play.api.test.Helpers.FIREFOX){
        browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333")
        browser.pageSource must contain("Hello")
      }
    }
  }
```

If you use firefox, it is a good idea to load the most recent selenium driver for it.

Comment: This has not worked for me yet. Based on what I found out about the error messages I'm getting, it looks like my selenium driver is not compatible with my firefox (version 24). How do I "load the most recent selenium driver"? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind. I took a closer look at your github page and saw that you had added it as a dependency. Works now. Not sure exactly what it ran by default when I didn't add the dependency.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are using WithBrowser to test your websocket, but this is
  how I'm doing it:

```
class ApplicationSpec extends Specification {

  "Application" should {
    "work" in {
      running(TestServer(9000)) {
        val client = new WebSocketClient(URI.create("ws://localhost:9000/test"),
          new Draft_17(), Map("HeaderKey1" -> "HeaderValue1"), 0) {

          def onError(p1: Exception) {
            println("onError")
          }

          def onMessage(message: String) {
            println("onMessage, message = " + message)
          }

          def onClose(code: Int, reason: String, remote: Boolean) {
            println("onClose")
          }

          def onOpen(handshakedata: ServerHandshake) {
            println("onOpen")
          }
        }
        client.connectBlocking()
        client.send("message")

        Thread.sleep(1000)
        success
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using [Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/) to call the websocket. This library can even send
custom http headers during the handshake.

Note that I don't do any assertions, so I have to return success at the end of the test.
I need a Thread.sleep, otherwise a RuntimeException ("There is no started application") can happen because the test finishes before the websocket communication is complete.